# Grails render map as JSON problems

Tags: json, grails, dictionary

I have some code that needs to convert a map in grails to JSON. I used grails converter to convert map to JSON object as follows:

```
def map=[:].withDefault { [] }
...
def users=service?.staff.each{map<<[(it.id):it.firstName+" "+it.lastName]}
render map as JSON
```

If the map is empty I got this [:] after conversion which If I tried to parse using $.parseJSON I got the following error

```
JSON.parse: unexpected character
```

While If the map is not empty I got "[2:'Feras Odeh']" as json object which If I tried to parse I got

```
JSON.parse: expected ',' or ']' after array element
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I don't see you converting your map to JSON in your question?  Your map isn't going to be JSON formatted by default.

Comment: sorry. I forgot to include this line

Answer (score 0):

```
import grails.converters.*;
```

...

```
List users = service?.staff.collect{[it.id: "${it.firstName} ${it.lastName}"]}
render(users as JSON)
```